# Is there an interactive PHP testing tool for Drupal?

Tags: 7

I'm in the middle of trying to create some contextphp code and drupal_set_message debugging is getting old fast. Is there any tool that would allow me to specify a url "context" (e.g. /node/6) and then have a PHP editor that could dynamically execute the code in the window as if it was running in that context?

Comment: Try devel module.

Comment: It's been a while since I really dug into devel. Looks like it's got something similar in the Firebug plugin (but then I need to run Firefox instead of Chrome). It would be nice to have a cross-browser solution.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug

Comment: [Drupal for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drupal-for-chrome/imlijcpfmhmifofiihbofoamohkdbblc) should mean you don't have to use the memory hog that is Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. I don't even have Firefox installed on my dev machine. That Chrome plugin should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running locally, you can install Netbeans and Xdebug and set break points, watches and everything.

If you want just a little better then [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6) you can run devel and the output from [dpm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/6) will be formatted by Krumo. That's at least helpful.

Comment: I'm going to have to look at the Netbeans option eventually. My issue isn't with the dsm output. It's the whole update php code in context, save, switch to another window, refresh, examine output, back to context, click edit, click php, resize code window, edit, repeat cycle.